# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'odata' Python

Tags: python, pip, odata

I have installed the following pip on the anaconda power shell using: `pip install -U pyodata`. The pip installed successfully, however when I try to import the script in Python `from pyodata import ODataService` I get the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'odata'`

Would like to know if someone experienced the same problem?

Comment: Looking through the [pyodata documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/pyodata/downloads/pdf/stable/) I don't see your usage example.  Normally a client is obtained for the web service (see user guide in session 3).  Also dir(pyodata) shows it only contains the following: `['Client',
 '__all__',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 'client',
 'exceptions',
 'v2']` which also shows you should create a client using `client = pyodata.Client(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont really kown about pyodata but there seems to be a ODataService module in odata.
https://github.com/tuomur/python-odata/blob/master/README.md
However this module is outdated, the current module can be found here: https://github.com/SAP/python-pyodata

Comment: are you sure these are the same, because there is another git for pyodata https://github.com/SAP/python-pyodata

Comment: Your second like is the correct module. The other one is outdated, maybe you should paste your second link in the answer so the others can benefit from it to. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like user copy-paste error during coding, mismatching two different packages.

Pyodata so far never had `OdataService`. Correct initialization is documented here: https://pyodata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/initialization.html

Comment: Keep in mind that linked content is not considered part of an answer here. Without it the answering part of this is tiny. Please provide a little more of a solution summary here.